# Pandas Series split n times

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to split a `pandas.Series` by the *first* piece of whitespace only.

`pd.Series.str.split` offers an `n` parameter which according to the inline help kind of sounds like it should specify how many splits to perform. (it says `Both 0 and -1 will be interpreted as return all splits` in the notes, but doesn't actually specify what it does!)

In any case, it doesn't appear to work:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame(['Split Once', 'Split Once As Well!'])
>>> x[0].str.split(n=1)
0               [Split, Once]
1    [Split, Once, As, Well!]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this seems to be a bug; you need to specify `pat` for it so it respects the value of `n`:

```
x[0].str.split( n=1, pat=' ' )
```

these are the lines in the source code which shows it ignores `n` if `pat` is `None`:

```
# pandas/core/strings.py
def str_split(arr, pat=None, n=None):
    if pat is None:
        if n is None or n == 0:
            n = -1
        f = lambda x: x.split()
...
```

edit: reported on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6466)

Comment: Yes! Also, you don't have to name the `pat` parameter, you can just put it first.